NextJs Supabase: Update Failed to fetch error message but update is done
I started a new project using NextJs (15.0.1) and supabase.
The first page reading data from supabase was no problem, even the realtime updates worked out.
I then tried to create a update some entities in the database.
This is my code to update one instance:
  const handleToggleActive = () => {
    const updatedStatus = !is_active; // Toggle the status

    supabase
      .from("User")
      .update({ is_active: updatedStatus })
      .eq("id", id)
      .then(({ error }) => {
        if (error) {
          console.error("Error updating user status:", error);
        } else {
          console.log("User status updated successfully");
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Unexpected error updating user status:", error);
      });
  };

(User is a by me created table, its not the supabase users table).
This request always ends up in this error:
{
    "message": "TypeError: Failed to fetch",
    "details": "TypeError: Failed to fetch\n    at eval (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/@supabase/supabase-js/dist/module/lib/fetch.js:30:25)\n    at eval (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/@supabase/supabase-js/dist/module/lib/fetch.js:51:16)\n    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)\n    at fulfilled (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/@supabase/supabase-js/dist/module/lib/fetch.js:11:58)",
    "hint": "",
    "code": ""
}

In the network tab the requests appears two times. One is done by a service worker (i dont know where this service worker comes from but i guess thats okay). The request done by the service worker works fine: it retrieves the expected success message 204. Therefore the data is updated.
Copying the request from the network tab and start it from postman is no problem either. The data is updated, response is 204, everything is fine.
Just NextJs has problems doing this request.
Do you have any idea, why the update request is not working?
I am happy for every hint! Thank you already
Things I tried to fix the bug

check the network tab

copy the request to postman

change between promise and await call

disable Row Level Security (RLS)

try to select data (works fine)


